# Symfony2 initial controller

Tags: php, symfony

I need to some tips to resolve my problem. I want to create something like initial controller for every request. Or mayby is better way?

This is my base.html.twig

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}W2 Symfony2{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            <link href="{{ asset('css/base.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
        {% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page_wrapper">
            {% block body %}
                <div id="header">
                    {% block header %}
                       {{ user }}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
                <div id="menu">
                    {% block menu %}
                       {{ item1 }}
                       {{ item2 }}
                       {{ item3 }}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    {% block footer %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and now I want to use one initial controller to set `blocks header, menu and footer` using methods from `src\Comflex\W2Bundle\Models\User.php` and `src\Comflex\W2Bundle\Models\Menu.php`.

```
        class InitialController extends Controller
        {
    public funtsion __construct()
    {
// code generates data for $user, $locales and others
        return $this->render(
                     '::base.html.twig',
                     array(
                        'user' => $user,
                        'locale' => $locale,
                        'menu' => array(
                            'item1', 'item2', 'item3',
                        )
                    )
                    );
        }
        }
```

Request like `www.site.com/web/app.php/home` will call `src\Comflex\W2Bundle\Controller\HomeController.php` but will changes only content of `block content`. Is that possible in Symfony2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fully clear what you're trying to achieve, nor what you've already tried. **You should read more docs and try something yourself before asking for help**.

Nevertheless, here are some tips.

**Embedding controllers**

You can render a controller inside a view with:

```
{% block menu %}
    {{ render(controller(
        'AppBundle:Menu:mainMenu',
        { 'max': 3 }
    )) }}    
{% endblock %}
```

If you embed it in a block, you'll be able to override it in templates.

Read more in "[Embedding controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers)".

**Calling code before every controller**

As explained in "[How to Set Up Before and After Filters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)", you can leverage event listeners to invoke code before or after the controller is called.

**Twig functions**

Twig functions might help you here as well. Have a look at [Functions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/index.html) in twig docs.

As for the menu you can have a look at how it's solved in the [KnpMenuBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle).

**Twig globals**

Have a look at "[How to Inject Variables into all Templates (i.e. global Variables)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html)".

Answer (score 0):

you confuse controller and Templating engine. You can reuse lot of frontal code without use the same controller.

You can read this templating philosophy : [Three level inheritance with twig](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#three-level-inheritance)

If you want process for all requests you can (but with very caution) also use the frontal controller symfony in web/ directory